# How to pull a carbon seatpost out of a carbon frame?

Tags: frames, carbon, seatpost

How do I pull out a carbon seatpost on a carbon frame?
It seems so hard for me...
Do I need a special tool, or just ask help from a local bike shop?

---

done with the seatpost.
I made the frame and fork reversed hold the bottom bracket with my tripod, install a saddle on it and gave a big bang on the saddle about 20 times and done.

Comment: I know that often the seatpost gets stuck in a regular steel bike with aluminum or steel post.  It sometimes helps to *gently* pry open the clamp.

Comment: I release the clamp already, still stack there...

Comment: Like I said, gently pry it open a hair.  And if the clamp isn't bonded to the seat tube, gently pry open the slit in the seat tube.

Comment: Can I insert the seatpost into seat tube up to 20cm ? thanks

Comment: I think, the best way is, visiting a local bike shop and ask for assistant since the shape of the seatpost is, aero seatpost and tear drop model

Comment: Generally (not specific to carbon) you can insert the seatpost down as far as it freely moves in the seat tube (it may bump into a water bottle boss, eg), and you can raise it up to the witness mark on the post.  For a specific bike there may be other restrictions based on how the seat tube is secured.

Comment: can i use heat gun for carbon seatpost stack into carbon frame ? will it damage the paint job ?

Comment: A hair dryer, maybe, but not a full-on heat gun -- too hot.  If your intent is to expand the outer tube, you could try wrapping the tube with rags dipped in very hot water.

Comment: Can I put 21cm into the seattube for Pinarello dogma 60.1? It seems, that's another possibility beside pulling it out and cut...

Comment: I reckon the heat gun question could be asked as a separate question on here, as it may have value to others

Comment: done with the seatpost already guys.....horay..... I made the frame and fork reversed hold the bottom bracket with my tripod, install a saddle on it and gave a big bang on the saddle about 20 times and done... Just like a climb, horay.....I finished the climb....

Thank you all for the advices...

Comment: Cervelo S3 fiber seatpost came out fine by doing exactly this:
"For Aero seatposts, smack the saddle nose solidly sideways with your hand, you should hear a loud crack, this is the surface tension breaking. Seatpost should then move OK."
Thanks for the tip, Neil!

Comment: Some minor commentary now that this question is active today: no matter what frame and seatpost material, it's probably best to re-grease it annually. I am not convinced that carbon paste is a must for carbon posts, since I believe it's basically standard grease with friction compounds to prevent slipping. (NB: if your post is slipping at its maximum torque, that's when you need carbon paste.) The main concern is galvanic corrosion between any two dissimilar metals. This includes titanium posts in non-titanium frames (copper anti-seize grease is recommended.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to push the seat down slightly.The carbon weave can act the way those finger cuff toys we had as children did (the more you pull the tighter they get).By pushing down you release the grabbing action.Make sure you use something similar to Park Tool Carbon/Alloy Assembly Lube before you reassemble it,check with your local bike shop for their reccomendation.

Comment: I will ask for local bike shop for a help, it's an aero seatpost and it's carbon....

Comment: I think, the best way is, visiting a local bike shop and ask for assistant since the shape of the seatpost is, aero seatpost and tear drop model...

Comment: can I insert another 10cm into the seat tube ? I have done 11cm inserted...

Comment: can i use wd40 or plusgas ?

Comment: i've been thinking, I put a saddle into the seatpost, put the frame upside down and try to hammer the saddle ...what do you think ?

Answer (score 8):

For Aero seatposts, smack the saddle nose solidly sideways with your hand, you should hear a loud crack, this is the surface tension breaking.  Seatpost should then move OK.  Saw this done by ex-Pro who was Giant dealer on a Propel, made my life so much easier since I learned that tip

Comment: Just to clarify, is this just for seat posts that can't rotate in the frame because they're not round ?     Cos seems like good advice for all seat posts regardless of the shape.

Comment: That's a great answer. Worked like a charm, thanks!
Do you have any idea wether some kind of lube needs to be used on Propel's aero seatpost? Didn't receive any in the box so i didn't use any.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and saved me a substantial amount of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Twisted the saddle as suggested above which worked a treat at breaking the friction.  I then used the flat part of a D-Lock (with a rag to stop metal on metal) under the front of the saddle as an upward hammer.  Job done after 3 clunks.

Answer (score 2):

I have an Aeropost that got stuck after I used my 2014 Giant Defy Advanced Carbon Fibre bike to commute (bike had to be stored in a cage outside during workday... in Canada therefore Fall temp btwn 1-10 degress).

The seat post is an Aero (tear drop shape) in a carbon frame.

Had been stuck for three years, but with a combination of [Carbomove](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/maintenance/oils-and-lubricants/penetrating-oil/effetto-mariposa-carbomove-review/) AND using this reversible clamp as a spread I was able to finally remove the seat post.

Technique involved spraying with Carbomove for a few days then, when the clamp arrived, using it as a spreader from the bottom bracket to the front of the seatpost... After a handful of squeezes on the clamp to apply outward pressure, the seat post popped out.

I called 15 otherwise really reputable bike shops and they all said it would be over $100 and may not get it out anyway. Oh and it may break your frame and almost certainly will ruin your seatpost...

Hope this helps others in the same spot.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

use drain cleaner, NaOH sodium hydroxide, in a syringe or in drops. make a fully saturated solution with water and drip those drops down the edge. let it work its magic. this can be used to dissolve the whole tube as well. you need to keep it warm to make it work. I used a blowtorch on the tube outdoors to keep it warm.

take off the seat and use a vice to hold the tube esp if it is excentric on the top. twist the fram. try some lube.  Not sure exactly what worked but that is what i tried and it worked. Anyone got an idea how to twist the alu sleve back in position though?

Comment: It sounds like NaOH can dissolve the resin; wouldn't this destroy the seat tube as well?

Comment: If you're managed to remove the aluminium liner sleeve from the frame, then this solution probably isn't ideal.